# How to get URL from Google Collab file inside the workspace?

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

How can I preview files in google collab?
You could convert them into base64 urls but for a video that is too much, is there a way to get the blob url from a file, the way Get file url from google collab, they way

```py
from google.colab import files
files.download('myfile.mp4')
```

does it, instead of downloading it, I want to preview it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload the video file to colab, you can use `HTML` from IPython.display.
To upload video:

```
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
```

To view video:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
from base64 import b64encode
video_path = 'video_name.mp4'

mp4 = open(video_path,'rb').read()
decoded_vid = "data:video/mp4;base64," + b64encode(mp4).decode()
HTML(f'<video width=400 controls><source src={decoded_vid} type="video/mp4"></video>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I made another version, using `nbextensions` trick to serve web content.

```py
def Video(fname, width=400):
  from IPython.display import HTML
  !cp $fname /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/v.mp4
  return HTML(f"<video width={width} src='/nbextensions/v.mp4' controls/>")
```

For a big file, you may want to cut it smaller first

```
!ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00 -to 05:00 -codec copy output.mp4
```

Original base64-encoded version

```py
def Video(fname, width=400):
  from IPython.display import HTML
  from base64 import b64encode
  mp4 = open(fname,'rb').read()
  url = "data:video/mp4;base64," + b64encode(mp4).decode()
  return HTML(f"<video width={width} controls src='{url}'/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers rely on using base64, this uses too much memory and it's server-side nor client side efficient.
With this method I manage to get a blob url from google collab, but it's a bit pesky to get right.

If you look at the source code at
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/google/colab/files.py#L159
You will see at line 159 the following

```py
_output.eval_js(
     """
     (async function() {
       const response = await fetch('https://localhost:%(port)d%(path)s');
       if (!response.ok) {
         throw new Error('Failed to download: ' + response.statusText);
       }
       const blob = await response.blob();
       const a = document.createElement('a');
       a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       a.download = '%(name)s';
       document.body.appendChild(a);
       a.click();
       a.remove();
     })();
 """ % {
     'port': port,
     'path': _os.path.abspath(filename),
     'name': _os.path.basename(filename),
 })
```

I copied the whole source code in google collaboratory and replaced this fragment with

```py
  display(HTML( ("""
  <div id=\"put\">Wait for the video to load/download</div><script>
      (async function() {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:%(port)d%(path)s');
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to download: ' + response.statusText);
        }
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = '%(name)s';
        a.innerHTML="download file here"
        document.getElementById("put").innerHTML=`<video width="960" height="720" controls>
  <source src="${a.href}" type="video/mp4">
</video>`
        document.getElementById("put").appendChild(a);
        //document.write(a);
        //a.click();
        //a.remove();
      })();
      </script>
  """ % {
      'port': port,
      'path': _os.path.abspath(filename),
      'name': _os.path.basename(filename),
  })))
```

This worked for me perfectly, I didn't understand much of the code, but I don't need to, I don't have to deal with those inefficient base64 urls!
Someone could make a wrapper function around it, I'm pretty sure it will be very helpful to someone.